# Android Facebook API - Active Token Error when using a valid token

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am receiving an error saying that I must have an active access token to query information about the current user, however the Facebook object is saying that my session is valid.

The code is:

```
private List<Integer> getFriendsList() throws FacebookError,
        MalformedURLException, JSONException, IOException {
    System.out.println(fbActivity.getFacebookConnector().getFacebook()
            .isSessionValid());
    JSONObject json = fbActivity.getFacebookConnector().makeRequest(
            "me/friends?fields=installed");
}
```

isSessionValid() returns true, however on the next line makeRequest() throws a FacebookError exception for using an invalid token.

Any help is most appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Also when I put the token into the token debugger it says it is valid and doesn't expire until August...

Answer (score 0):

To read the friends list you need to add the extended permissions while requesting for permissions.

Go though [THIS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) link to get a brief about the permissions and at the end there is also information about the access_tokens.

You might have requested permission to get only the basic information, so your log in session is valid but you do not have access to read the friends list.

In case you have the permission and still getting the error then please add additional log info so that I can guide you in the right direction.